# reference to table from another schema in oracle

Tags: oracle, reference

I have 2 different schemas ( finn, hr ).
I have a table from hr whose name is ( hr_employee_info_tbl ) and another table from finn whose name is FINN_BUDGET_TBL.
I tried to make a reference from FINN_BUDGET_TBL to hr_employee_info_tbl but get ora-01031 insufficient privileges.

which privilige i have to grant my user?

-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints

```
alter table FINN_BUDGET_TBL
  add constraint employee_id_fk foreign key (EMPLOYEE_ID)
  references hr.hr_employee_info_tbl (EMPLOYEE_INFO_ID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connected with user hr, run:

```
grant select on hr.hr_employee_info_tbl to finn;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are logging in as the owner of FINN_BUDGET_TBL (in this case FINN) and the current logged in user has read on the hr schema.

```
grant select on hr.hr_employee_info_tbl to FINN;
```

"Alter any table" to the current user (FINN) also might work, but is in general, not the right thing to do.

Comment: Did you login as FINN and make sure you were able to select from the table?